# Thinking Sphinx not indexing associated data to model searched by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

In my Product.rb

```ruby
 define_index do
     indexes :name, :sortable => true
     indexes brand

     has :id, kosher_id, gluten_free_id, lactose_free_id
     has stores(:id),        :as => 'store_ids'
     has locations(:id),     :as => 'location_ids'
     has categories(:id),    :as => 'category_ids'
     has kosher(:passover),  :as => 'kosher_passover'
   end
```

In my Searching Class

```ruby
  def self.for_locations_by_query(query, options = {})
     query, categories = @@coder.decode(query).gsub(/(\b\w+\b)/, "+\\0"), @@coder.decode(options.delete(:categories))
     origin, page = @@coder.decode(options.delete(:origin)), @@coder.decode(options.delete(:page))
     per_page, sort_order = @@coder.decode(options.delete(:per_page)), @@coder.decode(options.delete(:sort_order))
     distance, classifications = @@coder.decode(options.delete(:distance)), @@coder.decode(options.delete(:classifications))

     with                        = {}
     with[:store_ids]            = Location.all(:origin => origin, :within => distance).collect(&:store_id).uniq unless origin.blank? or distance.blank?
     with[:category_ids]         = categories.split(',') unless categories.blank?

     without                     = {}
     without[:kosher_id]         = 0 if classifications.split(',').include? 'kosher'
     without[:gluten_free_id]    = 0 if classifications.split(',').include? 'gluten_free'
     without[:lactose_free_id]   = 0 if classifications.split(',').include? 'lactose_free'
     without[:kosher_passover]   = 0 if classifications.split(',').include? 'kosher_passover'

     products  = Product.search(query, :with => with, :without => without, :per_page => 20, :page => 1)
     stores    = products.collect { |p| p.stores }.flatten.uniq
     locations = stores.collect { |s| s.locations.find(:all, :origin => origin, :within => distance) }.flatten.uniq
     locations.sort_by_distance_from(origin)
     locations.each { |l| l.dist = l.distance }

     locations = locations.paginate(:page => page, :per_page => per_page)

     return { :total_entries => locations.total_entries, :size => locations.size, :locations => locations }
    end
```

*.sphinx.conf file - product model

```ruby
source product_core_0
{
  type = mysql
  sql_host = [FILTERED]
  sql_user = [FILTERED]
  sql_pass = [FILTERED]
  sql_db = [FILTERED]
  sql_sock = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
  sql_query_pre = SET TIME_ZONE = '+0:00'
  sql_query = SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `products`.`id` * 3 + 1 AS `id` , `products`.`name` AS `name`, `products`.`brand` AS `brand`, `products`.`id` AS `sphinx_internal_id`, 485965105 AS `class_crc`, 0 AS `sphinx_deleted`, IFNULL(`products`.`name`, '') AS `name_sort`, `products`.`id` AS `id`, `products`.`kosher_id` AS `kosher_id`, `products`.`gluten_free_id` AS `gluten_free_id`, `products`.`lactose_free_id` AS `lactose_free_id`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IFNULL(`stores`.`id`, '0') SEPARATOR ',') AS `store_ids`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IFNULL(`locations`.`id`, '0') SEPARATOR ',') AS `location_ids`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IFNULL(`categories`.`id`, '0') SEPARATOR ',') AS `category_ids`, `koshers`.`passover` AS `kosher_passover` FROM `products`    LEFT OUTER JOIN `product_stores` ON (`products`.`id` = `product_stores`.`product_id`)  LEFT OUTER JOIN `stores` ON (`stores`.`id` = `product_stores`.`store_id`)   LEFT OUTER JOIN `product_locations` ON (`products`.`id` = `product_locations`.`product_id`)  LEFT OUTER JOIN `locations` ON (`locations`.`id` = `product_locations`.`location_id`)   LEFT OUTER JOIN `category_products` ON (`products`.`id` = `category_products`.`product_id`)  LEFT OUTER JOIN `categories` ON (`categories`.`id` = `category_products`.`category_id`)   LEFT OUTER JOIN `koshers` ON `koshers`.id = `products`.kosher_id  WHERE `products`.`id` >= $start AND `products`.`id` <= $end GROUP BY `products`.`id`  ORDER BY NULL
  sql_query_range = SELECT IFNULL(MIN(`id`), 1), IFNULL(MAX(`id`), 1) FROM `products` 
  sql_attr_uint = sphinx_internal_id
  sql_attr_uint = class_crc
  sql_attr_uint = sphinx_deleted
  sql_attr_uint = id
  sql_attr_uint = kosher_id
  sql_attr_uint = gluten_free_id
  sql_attr_uint = lactose_free_id
  sql_attr_bool = kosher_passover
  sql_attr_str2ordinal = name_sort
  sql_attr_multi = uint store_ids from field
  sql_attr_multi = uint location_ids from field
  sql_attr_multi = uint category_ids from field
  sql_query_info = SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `id` = (($id - 1) / 3)
}

index product_core
{
  source = product_core_0
  path = [FILTERED]/releases/20101008215652/db/sphinx/staging/product_core
  charset_type = utf-8
}

index product
{
  type = distributed
  local = product_core
}
```

The problematic line is `with[:store_ids] = ...`
The product can be associated to multiple store ids, however it only seems to work if the lowest numbered `ID` is in the array for `with[:store_ids]`.  For example, the ids associated with product `1000` are `[12,15,41]`, if `with[:store_ids] = [15,41]` then 0 results are returned, however if `12` is in the array then it works.

I have stopped, started, restarted, reindexed, rebuilt, generated a new conf file for sphinx, and repeated in various orders and I have had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do with permissions and the Capistrano release directory structure.  The service was owned by root, was running from an older release, and would not stop with a user level rake ts:stop, it required me to run it as root and then start the service from the current release directory.  At that point, the data is being displayed correctly.